# How to use a HTC Tattoo as a modem on a Mac?

Tags: 1.6-donut, htc-tattoo

I've tried to use HTC Tattoo as a modem on a Windows PC and it worked well, but on a Mac it doesn't work.

Some trick or app that i should be aware?

My HTC Tattoo uses the default 1.6 ROM with Sense.

Thanks.

Comment: How did you use it with Windows?  I'm assuming HTC has Windows software to manage it.

Comment: When i plug-in the option to "use as a modem" appear on the phone.

Comment: Oh wow, that's interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hopefully the Mac version of [PdaNet for Android](http://junefabrics.com/android/index.php) will do this for you.  There's a trial period, after which you need to buy it if you want to browse secure (https:// …) sites.  Signing into Gmail requires HTTPS, for example.